# Extract images using jsoup that have no img tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to extract images that are within the div and the src isn't listed within an img tag. I cannot do a getElementById() either since it varies from page to page. Is there some regex I can use to extract the images from doc for such cases? Any help is appreciated.

HTML snippet:

```
<div 
    class="rendition-bg rendition-bg--alignment desktop-center-center mobile-center-center" 
    data-src="/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default- 
mobile/image.jpg" 
    data-mobile-rendition="/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
    data-tablet-rendition="/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
    data-desktop- rendition="/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-desktop/image.jpg" 
    style="background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default- 
mobile/image.jpg&quot;);">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to extract paths to all images in div attrs and what are those "transform" after ".jpg"? How do you want to treat them? Should they be considered part of a next path? Or thrown away as a delimeter?

Comment: @GaponenkoAndrei Yes, I want to extract all the paths as long as they are images. The "transform" part can be thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

Far from elegant or easy solution, but here is something that, hopefully, can give you some start:

```
    String snippet =
      "<div class=\"rendition-bg rendition-bg--alignment desktop-center-center" +
        "mobile-center-center \" data-src=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-" +
        "mobile/image.jpg\" data-mobile- \n" +
        "rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg\" data-" +
        "tablet-rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg\"" +
        "data-desktop- rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-desktop/image.jpg\"" +
        "style=\"background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-" +
        "mobile/image.jpg&quot;);\"></div>";

    List<String> imgAttrs =
      Jsoup.parse(snippet)
        .getElementsByTag("div")
        .stream()
        // get lists of attributes
        .map(Element::attributes)
        // flatten all attrs to single list
        .flatMap(attrs -> attrs.asList().stream())
        // filter attributes
        .filter(attribute -> attribute.getValue() != null && attribute.getValue().contains(".jpg"))
        // map to values
        .map(Attribute::getValue)
        // replace all ".transform" with a whitespace
        .map(attrValue -> attrValue.replace(".transform", " "))
        // get url value of a "background-image"
        .map(attrValue -> getUrlFromBackgroundImage(attrValue))
        // split attributes by whitespaces
        .flatMap(attrValue -> Stream.of(attrValue.split(" ")))
        .collect(toList());
      }

     private static String getUrlFromBackgroundImage(final String backgroundImage) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("background-image:[ ]?url\\((['\"]?(.*?\\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)(\\s)?)*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(backgroundImage);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : backgroundImage;
     }
```

The contents of imgAttrs should be:

```
/content/dam/Image.jpg
/default-mobile/image.jpg
/content/dam/Image.jpg
/default-desktop/image.jpg
/content/dam/Image.jpg
/default-mobile/image.jpg
"/content/dam/Image.jpg
/default-mobile/image.jpg
```

Not sure if that's what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in comments:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
        "<div class=\"rendition-bg rendition-bg--alignment desktop-center-center mobile-center-center \" "
        + "data-src=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg\" "
        + "data-mobile-rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg\" "
        + "data-tablet-rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg\" "
        + "data-desktop-rendition=\"/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-desktop/image.jpg\" "
        + "style=\"background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg&quot;);\"></div>");

    // select all elements with "data-src" attribute, but here we use only the first of them
    Map<String, String> dataAttributes = doc.select("[data-src]").first().dataset();

    // here we have all data attributes of this element:
    System.out.println(dataAttributes);

    // you can access them like this:
    System.out.println(dataAttributes.get("mobile-rendition"));
    System.out.println(dataAttributes.get("tablet-rendition"));
    System.out.println(dataAttributes.get("desktop-rendition"));

    // split and create list of urls (contains duplicates)
    List<String> urls = dataAttributes.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getValue().split("\\.transform")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // if you need only unique urls use this one instead:
    //  Set<String> urls = dataAttributes.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getValue().split(".transform"))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing the div closely, we can see that there are 2 images referenced. They are

```
data-src=                  "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
data-mobile-rendition=     "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
data-tablet-rendition=     "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
data-desktop- rendition=   "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-desktop/image.jpg" 
style="background-image: url/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg
```

Of these four image references 3 are referring to the same image while another one is referring to a desktop ~ image. So if we need to extract URL for these two images:

```
data-src=                  "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-mobile/image.jpg" 
data-desktop- rendition=   "/content/dam/Image.jpg.transform/default-desktop/image.jpg"
```

We can use the following code:

```
        Elements els = doc.select("div.rendition-bg");
        for (Element ele :els){
                System.out.println(ele.absUrl("data-src"));
                System.out.println(ele.absUrl("data-desktop-"));                
            }
```

Let me know if I have understood your requirement correctly.